# Does .toString(16) always return lowercase?

Tags: javascript, tostring

When converting a decimal number to a base above 10 using `.toString(base)`, it seems that I always get a lower case string. **Can I rely on this**? An upper case string would be correct, although would need converting for my application.

Extra credit for referencing the part of the spec that defines this (I looked and couldn't find it) and for any counter-examples (browsers that return uppercase).

Example:

```
(12648430).toString(16) // returns: "c0ffee". Not "C0FFEE"
```

Comment: You can rely on this, but I don't think you should. If the case is really that important, just add `toLowerCase` where appropriate and stop worrying about it.

Comment: It would be a shame to send out an update to all customers with this code deployed if it isn't necessary. As existing browsers _are_ compatible and future browsers _must_ be compatible, I'll leave the old code as it is.

Comment: Up to you, but if one day your code breaks and your only excuse will be "someone on SO told me my code's fine" - _that_ will be a shame!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes**, it's always lower case. That's been defined in the specification since the 5th edition in 2009. Here's what it says in [the 5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2); 5.0 isn't directly linkable, but it said much the same thing:

> If ToInteger(*radix*) is not an integer between 2 and 36 inclusive throw a **RangeError** exception. If ToInteger(*radix*) is an integer from 2 to 36, but not 10, the result is a String representation of this Number value using the specified radix. **Letters a-z are used for digits with values 10 through 35.** The precise algorithm is implementation-dependent if the radix is not 10, however the algorithm should be a generalisation of that specified in 9.8.1.

*(my emphasis)*

The [current spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.tostring) continues to specify using `a-z` (in lower case).

Previously, the 3rd edition spec (there was no 4th edition) from 1999 did not say that, it just said:

> If radix is an integer from 2 to 36, but not 10, the result is a string, the choice of which is implementation-dependent.

...but now that browsers that were created when the 3rd edition spec was the current spec are well and truly gone, you can rely on it being in lower case. And indeed, you probably could even when this answer was first posted in 2013, since they didn't usually add that kind of thing to the specification if there were *significant* known implementations that did something different.

Just for fun, here's a quick check:

```js
const str = (12648430).toString(16);
console.log(`${str} === c0ffee? ${str === "c0ffee"}`);
```

Comment: You've convinced me! No `.toLowerCase()` for me. I'll also test in IE5 at some point and post an update.

Comment: @ColBeseder: :-) FWIW, I agree with thg435. I wouldn't push an update *just* for that, but I'd be pretty tempted to include it in whatever update I was pushing next. Then again, if you have a robust test suite, there's no need -- the test suite will pick up the problem if you add support for some obscure engine that doesn't handle this correctly (as of the 5th ed. spec).

Answer (score 1):

(12648430).toString(16) will always return: "c0ffee". Not "C0FFEE", after checking it with somes browsers, I found a confirmation:

> The Number object overrides the toString() method of the Object object; it does not
> inherit Object.prototype.toString(). For Number objects, the toString() method returns a
> string representation of the object in the specified radix.
>
> The toString() method parses its first argument, and attempts to return a string
> representation in the specified radix (base). For radixes above 10, the letters of the
> alphabet indicate numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16),
> a through f are used.

#### "for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), a through f are used".

See reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString .